# How to implement entities with a many-to-many association to be able to save a root object using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-many

I have two entities:

```
    public class Group
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        private ICollection<Item> _items = new HashSet<Item>();
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I use automapping with the following override:

```
automapping.Override<Group>(m => m.HasManyToMany(_ => _.Items).AsSet());
```

I construct a group object and few items adding them to the group object. When I save the group object using `session.Save(group)` the exception occurs:

NHibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing. Type: NhResearch.ManyToManyTests+Item, Entity: 0 item1
at NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys.GetEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(String entityName, Object entity, ISessionImplementor session)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a cascade setting.

```
m => m.HasManyToMany(_ => _.Items).AsSet().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
```

All - if you want to save update and delete items

AllDeleteOrphan - same as all, but also deletes orphaned items

SaveUpdate - cascade on save or update

Delete - cascade only deleted items

FYI, you're also likely missing the Table specification and the parent and child key columns.

Comment: SaveUpdate did the job. Thanks